# Implementing two factor in django

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to add two factor authentication to my django app. I'm following [this library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth). As the [doc](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) says, i added the library to my Django settings and i added `url(r'', include(tf_urls)),` to my urls.

I'm kind of stuck here, though. What the doc doesn't explain is how integrate the 2fa login on my own login, how i can add a settings page to generate, enable and disable the 2fa keys, so i don't really know how to go forward from here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean 'i'm stuck'? What's the problem? Error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Edited the post, to make it a bit more specific

Comment: Have you studied the example project? https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/example

Comment: @AKX Yes, i did not understand some parts of it, though. For example, on the views.py there is no login view, it looks like it's calling the login from a core.py file. That is a bit confusing, since i already have my own login and i don't need to use another one.

Comment: You'll need to use the 2FA-enabled login view/wizard, or adapt it, if you want 2FA there.

Comment: /account/login is defined by tf_urls and basically loads the 2FA login view. You'll just want to replace the basic templates used, which is what the example project does: it only changes a couple of templates, but basically everything is already in the core 2FA app. You can of course subclass the views to customise further, e.g. `two-factor.views.core.LoginView`

Comment: @dirkgroten but what if, for example, i want to add a captcha to my login form? I mean, how do i edit the login view? Do i need to go into the core and edit it from there?

Comment: You mean in the registration form... nobody puts a captcha in a login form that would be awful. In that case you override the url pattern to point to your own view, subclass the core view and just override the minimum needed to make it work. But I don’t see a need to do that for the login view, which is a bit complex. Adding the same url pattern above the included ones will catch yours first before reaching the two_factor one.

Comment: So basically, if now i have my own login view with my form i'll need to override it and just use the core login?

Comment: yes, you should use the core login view and form, since it's built as a 3-step process (first login, then present the form for the token, then, if token is lost, present form for backup tokens). You probably just need to override the templates to use your own. And if you have a login url that not /account/login, use that to point to the new view and disable the /account/login one. You're free to use the provided urls or not.